# How do I parse entire Common Crawl database using node?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to get as many html files from Common Crawl database as possible. I'm quite lost on how to do it, and don't even know how to start. I've seen many people doing it in python, but I don't know how to adequate the code to javascript. I found this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/commoncrawl

But this package can only search, and not parse through every single website of the database.
Also, I want the raw html data from the websites only, and a way to get the link of the website. Shouldn't be that hard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [commoncrawl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/commoncrawl) package looks like it is used for navigating their [CDX indexes](https://commoncrawl.org/2015/04/announcing-the-common-crawl-index/).

If you want the underlying HTML itself, you need to be inspecting the WARC files. Consider using something like [node-warc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-warc).

I wrote a blog post that introduces the WARC format and provides examples on how to [fetch and search HTML from the Common Crawl](https://code402.com/hello-warc-common-crawl-code-samples) in Node, Java, Go and Python. You can find the Node code on Github [here](https://github.com/code402/warc-benchmark/tree/master/node). Hope that helps!